# How to start international research collaborations within a specialised medical field

Tags: collaboration, international, multidisciplinary

I am a researcher with 11 years of experience working on a series of projects in the health and education fields. These projects are loosely linked in that they are psych/ social science based and mostly involve quantitative methodology (e.g. training and development for mid career and older workers, workplace health and safety, inclusive education for children with autism and other disabilities).

However, I have developed a special interest in researching psychosocial health/ quality of life in people with congenital heart disease.

There are no researchers in my country investigating this topic (that I am aware of), however I have identified several researchers and groups internationally.

I would be interested in collaborating with them applying my experience to create different approaches to improving patient outcomes (e.g. flexible work policies/ career guidance for teens and adults, inclusive education for school aged children, positive psychology).

My strategy is to read some of these researchers' works in detail and then contact them with my ideas. I was wondering if I have the right idea or whether I am on the wrong track entirely? I don't have much experience with collaboration.

Comment: It would be easier if you "knew someone that knows someone". Introductions, even indirect, would help to give your proposal more credibility.

Comment: Thank you! I have since found a couple of local (ish) people doing PhD's in this area who might have contacted these researchers - so I will see if they know anything and are willing to share information.